# Migration Django 1.4.5 -> 1.6.5: ListView, DetailView

Tags: python, django, migration, django-1.6

I am trying to migrate my project from Django 1.4.5 to 1.6.5

Django 1.4.5 code:

```
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list, object_detail
..
return object_list(request, groups, paginate_by = 20, template_object_name = 'group', extra_context = args)
return object_detail(request, queryset, id, template_object_name = 'group')
```

**Question:** how the code above supposed to look in 1.6.5?

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
..
return ????
```

Comment: See this related article: [How to migrate from function-based generic views to class-based analogs in Django](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2013/12/come-migrare-dalle-viste-generiche-basate-su-funzioni-alle-analoghe-basate-su-classi-in-django/).

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, the correct answer for *ListView* is:

```
class TestsListView(ListView):
    extra_context = {}
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TestsListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(self.extra_context)
        return context
...
callable = TestsListView.as_view(queryset = groups, template_name = None, paginate_by = 20, context_object_name = 'group_list', extra_context = args)
return callable(request)
```